# Can't get Sendmail to connect to MIMEDefang

Tags: sendmail, milter

I would like to set a milter using MIMEDefang on Ubuntu 16.04. I have an existing server using Sendmail 8.15.2-3. I installed MIMEDefang 2.78-1ubuntu1.1 (default package from apt). I configured my filter as I wanted and the service seems to be running. I can't seem to get sendmail to connect to the milter through.

I originally tried adding this line to my sendmail.mc line:

```
INPUT_MAIL_FILTER(`mimedefang', `S=unix:/var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang.sock, F=T, T=S:1m;R:1m')
```

but with that configuration I no one can send mail and the log file shows:

```
May 23 11:21:52  sm-mta[17052]: w4NFLq30017052: Milter (mimedefang): local socket name /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang.sock unsafe
May 23 11:21:52  sm-mta[17052]: w4NFLq30017052: Milter (mimedefang): 
to error state
May 23 11:21:52  sm-mta[17052]: w4NFLq30017052: Milter: initialization failed, temp failing commands
```

I can see the socket listing by running `netstat -na | grep fang`

```
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     154381   /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang-multiplexor.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     154399   /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang.sock
```

But if I list the contents of /var/spool/MIMEDefang the socket isn't listed (`ls -l /var/spool/MIMEDefang`):

```
total 8
-rw------- 1 defang defang 6 May 23 15:15 mimedefang-multiplexor.pid
srwx------ 1 defang defang 0 May 23 15:15 mimedefang-multiplexor.sock
-rw------- 1 defang defang 6 May 23 15:15 mimedefang.pid
```

I didn't think it was the answer but I tried linking sendmail to mimedefang-multiplexor.sock since I didn't see mimedefang.sock in the `ls` but since I got different error. If that is what I'm supposed to do then I'm asking the wrong question.

I feel as though I'm missing something obvious.

**Edit:** As best I can tell from the service status mimedefang seems to have started correctly:

```
● mimedefang.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mimedefang; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-05-23 16:51:17 EDT; 4min 34s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 21578 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mimedefang stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20006 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/mimedefang reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 21587 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mimedefang start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 8
   Memory: 20.8M
      CPU: 122ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mimedefang.service
           ├─21617 /usr/bin/mimedefang-multiplexor -p /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang-multiplexor.pid -E -z /var/spool/MIMEDefang -m 2 -x 10 -U defang -b 600 -l -y 0 -s /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang-multiplexor.sock
           ├─21634 /usr/bin/mimedefang -P /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang.pid -R -1 -m /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang-multiplexor.sock -z /var/spool/MIMEDefang -U defang -s  -p /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang.sock
           ├─21636 /usr/bin/mimedefang-multiplexor -p /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang-multiplexor.pid -E -z /var/spool/MIMEDefang -m 2 -x 10 -U defang -b 600 -l -y 0 -s /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang-multiplexor.sock
           └─21647 /usr/bin/mimedefang-multiplexor -p /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang-multiplexor.pid -E -z /var/spool/MIMEDefang -m 2 -x 10 -U defang -b 600 -l -y 0 -s /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang-multiplexor.sock

May 23 16:51:17  systemd[1]: Starting mimedefang.service...
May 23 16:51:17  mimedefang[21587]: Starting mimedefang-multiplexor:                            [  OK  ]
May 23 16:51:17  mimedefang-multiplexor[21617]: started; minSlaves=2, maxSlaves=10, maxRequests=500, maxIdleTime=300, busyTimeout=600, clientTimeout=10
May 23 16:51:17  mimedefang[21634]: MIMEDefang alive. slavesReservedForLoopback=-1 AllowNewConnectionsToQueue=0 doRelayCheck=0 doHeloCheck=0 doSenderCheck=1 doRecipientCheck=0
May 23 16:51:17  mimedefang-multiplexor[21617]: Initialized embedded Perl interpreter
May 23 16:51:17  mimedefang-multiplexor[21617]: Starting slave 0 (pid 21636) (1 running): Bringing slaves up to minSlaves (2)
May 23 16:51:17  mimedefang[21634]: Multiplexor alive - entering main loop
May 23 16:51:17  mimedefang[21587]: Starting mimedefang:                                        [  OK  ]
May 23 16:51:17  systemd[1]: Started mimedefang.service.
May 23 16:51:20  mimedefang-multiplexor[21617]: Starting slave 1 (pid 21647) (2 running): Bringing slaves up to minSlaves (2)
```

The log here doesn't react at all to sendmail trying to use the normal MD socket. It does show an error (I think it was a timeout error) if I try the multiplexor socket.

Comment: It's mimedefang issue, independent of sendmail. For me `ls` shows that `mimedefang.sock` all right. Anything interesting in `systemctl status -l mimedefang` besides `Cannot read filter /etc/mail/mimedefang-filter`? Please edit it into the question. Probably the main process isn't running (`/usr/bin/mimedefang -P /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang.pid -R -1 -m /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang-multiplexor.sock -z /var/spool/MIMEDefang -U defang  -p /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang.sock`)

Comment: @kubanczyk I wanted to tag both pieces of software, but there isn't a mimedefang tag and I don't have enough rep to create one. I have edited the service status in but it looks good to me.

Comment: Status looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

After staring at the service status very closely I noticed the problem. If you look at the command listed in the status in the question it looks like this:

```
-U defang -s  -p /var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang.sock
```

The crucial thing to notice is that there are two space between the `-s` parameter and the `-p` parameter. I dove into `/etc/init.d/mimedefang` to investigate. I'm nowhere near an expert in bash but I noticed that the quotes on these lines seems suspicious:

```
`[ "$MD_SKIP_BAD_RCPTS" = "yes" ] && echo "-N"` \
"`[ -n "$X_SCANNED_BY" ] && \
        ( [ "$X_SCANNED_BY" = "-" ] && \
            echo "-X" || echo "-x$X_SCANNED_BY" )`" \
`[ "$ALLOW_NEW_CONNECTIONS_TO_QUEUE" = "yes" ] && echo "-q"` \
```

I suspected that even if `$X_SCANNED_BY` is not defined as it is in my case the white space between the commands would still be added. I wasn't sure what their purpose was and since my case doesn't use `$X_SCANNED_BY` I removed the outer quotes:

```
`[ "$MD_SKIP_BAD_RCPTS" = "yes" ] && echo "-N"` \
`[ -n "$X_SCANNED_BY" ] && \
        ( [ "$X_SCANNED_BY" = "-" ] && \
            echo "-X" || echo "-x$X_SCANNED_BY" )` \
`[ "$ALLOW_NEW_CONNECTIONS_TO_QUEUE" = "yes" ] && echo "-q"` \
```

After this the command only had a single space between the options and sock appears as it should in the `ls` results:

```
total 8
-rw------- 1 defang defang 6 May 24 10:29 mimedefang-multiplexor.pid
srwx------ 1 defang defang 0 May 24 10:29 mimedefang-multiplexor.sock
-rw------- 1 defang defang 6 May 24 10:29 mimedefang.pid
srwx------ 1 defang defang 0 May 24 10:29 mimedefang.sock
```

Finally Sendmail works without issue.

Comment: Qualifies as a bug to be handled by the package maintainer. Good find. (Also, no expert wrote this. It lacks clarity.)